# Crypto in Linux

Tags: linux, encryption, encryption-symmetric, crypt

I understand that in Linux kernel there are basically, 2 types of crypto options:

1. cryptodev (/dev/crypto)
2. AF_ALG

But in documentation, both methods are mentioned as HW encryption , i.e. methods which require HW support.

So, if I need crypto support in Linux, and does not have hw support , will the userspace API (for AF_ALG and cryptodev) still work ?

If yes - does it mean they use software algorithm in kernel ?

I am using Arria V, which is based on arm , yet, I don't see in its documentation mention of crypto, so I'm not sure it is supported in HW.

Comment: What is the exact name of your chip and arm core? Linux kernel version?

Comment: It's Arria V (altera/intel), kernel 4.1.x

Comment: Arria V which one (which column of the table https://www.altera.com/content/dam/altera-www/global/en_US/pdfs/literature/pt/arria-v-product-table.pdf or just exact board name or exact chip name 5A?????)? What is the ARM core (`cat /proc/cpuinfo`)? Where did you get your linux kernel, can you post `config` file of the kernel (sometimes it is available as `/proc/config.gz` or in /boot partition). Exact name of chip / CPU is needed to search for crypto accelerators in your HW, and kernel config - to check are crypto api enabled or not.

Comment: It's ARRIA V- SX from rocketboard https://rocketboards.org/foswiki/view/Documentation/GSRD

Comment: GSRD does not list ARRIA V-SX; and altera lists dual core [ARM Cortex-A9 MPcore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_Cortex-A9) CPU core (with NEON and VFPv3). Page https://www.altera.com/products/soc/portfolio/arria-v-soc/features.html don't list builtin crypto for HPS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overview of both methods: AF_ALG and cryptodev (`/dev/crypto`) https://events.linuxfoundation.org/sites/events/files/slides/lcj-2014-crypto-user.pdf#page=8 "Utilizing the crypto accelerators - Marek Vaˇsut - May 18, 2014"

As I understand, AF_ALG just uses [generic kernel crypto API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypto_API_(Linux)) and **may use hw crypto** accelerator, but **always can use software** crypto enabled in kernel. AF_ALG can be enabled in 4.1 kernel [by CONFIG_CRYPTO_USER_API option](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/crypto/Makefile?v=4.1#L99) set as 'y' or 'm' in kernel configuration when it was built (check config file of the kernel, sometimes it is available as /proc/config.gz or in /boot partition). And to use some algorithms (hashes, symmetric ciphers, random generators), corresponding  CONFIG_CRYPTO_USER_API suboption should be enabled too:

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/crypto/Kconfig?v=4.1#L1485

```
1485 config CRYPTO_USER_API
1486         tristate
1487 
1488 config CRYPTO_USER_API_HASH
1489         tristate "User-space interface for hash algorithms"
1490         depends on NET
1491         select CRYPTO_HASH
1492         select CRYPTO_USER_API
1493         help
1494           This option enables the user-spaces interface for hash
1495           algorithms.
1496 
1497 config CRYPTO_USER_API_SKCIPHER
1498         tristate "User-space interface for symmetric key cipher algorithms"
1499         depends on NET
1500         select CRYPTO_BLKCIPHER
1501         select CRYPTO_USER_API
1502         help
1503           This option enables the user-spaces interface for symmetric
1504           key cipher algorithms.
1505 
1506 config CRYPTO_USER_API_RNG
1507         tristate "User-space interface for random number generator algorithms"
1508         depends on NET
1509         select CRYPTO_RNG
1510         select CRYPTO_USER_API
1511         help
1512           This option enables the user-spaces interface for random
1513           number generator algorithms.
```

Cryptodev (http://cryptodev-linux.org/index.html) looks bit like out-of-tree driver, not included into standard kernel (empty search for http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=crypto_run or http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=cryptodev). It should be downloaded, built and installed by user (slide 10 of https://events.linuxfoundation.org/sites/events/files/slides/lcj-2014-crypto-user.pdf#page=10 "*Out of kernel tree code (for years)*"). They also claim on their website "Support for all major cipher and hash algorithms" so, it may use hardware crypto accelerator, but **will work for any supported algorithm** with software implementation when there is no hardware (there is always some crypto which is not implemented by any hardware).

> So, if I need crypto support in Linux, and does not have hw support , will the userspace API (for AF_ALG and cryptodev) still work?
>   If yes - does it mean they use software algorithm in kernel?

Yes, both methods will work without any HW crypto, and will use all software implementations available in the kernel (enabled at time when kernel was built).

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer. Just to complete, according to my understanding, when we deal with HW implementation, is it correct to assume that some vendors choose to implement driver in AF_ALG while other implement it in cryptodev ?

Comment: ransh, incorrect. Both AF_ALG and cryptodev just like proxy to generic Linux kernel Crypto API (check http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/crypto/Kconfig?v=4.1), and HW support is implemented in Linux kernel Crypto API. And other crypto hw is just CPU instructions like AES and SHA in Intel/AMD x86/amd64 or VIA, available to userspace programs (https://lauri.xn--vsandi-pxa.com/2014/07/cryptodev.html "Note that crypto hardware that has been implemented as instructions such as VIA Padlock [4] and Intel AES-NI [5] does not need any special mechanism to be used from userspace.")

Comment: HW crypto in linux kernel is implemented in "devices/crypto" directory, not the generic software "/crypto", and there are lists of supported hw like http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/crypto/Kconfig?v=4.1 for 4.1 or larger list http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/crypto/Kconfig for recent kernel